# calling a client side java method from server side html button?

Tags: java, android, html

Ok In an android vebview I have a java method.  Is it possible that when a button on the web page being viewed is hit to call that method? If so can you point me in the right direction?

I have done this in all java-script but now my method is in java.  Unless there is a way to convert the java method to java-script. I don't know just rambling there.

cross post url: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/d0a72c8414871d72?hl=en#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. There are quite a few examples that would help you.

One of them:
http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/10/android-webview-javascript-and-css.html

Comment: ok For some reason, (Hunger, Fatigue, Brain Fart) I missed the whole binding section.  Thanks I got it.